# Jitterbit: Attachments Issue

Tags: encoding, insert, attachment, jitterbit

I use Jitterbit and I have inserted attachments, but they are not showing correct data, showing some junk data when viewing the file after insert.
I used `Base64Encodefile("C:\Users\myPC\Desktop\Jitterbit data\Button Code")` option. But the attachment was not showed correctly when I tried  to open the attachment. `(«ë'r‡^ K®Ë'jH«jF§¶ Þ2Kh¤ ̃­μêÛμÖ­h ́7­j)lv'h)` this is the format that I see. Can you guys help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, you missed some step. Did you perform the "Expand “Cryptograph” Double click on Base64EncodeFile”" part correctly?